# Вывод изображения в таблицу по нажатию кнопки (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, button

Нужно сделать программу, появляется окно, где записываются данные, при нажатии на кнопку эти данные добавляются и в последнем столбике появляется изображение. Проблема заключается в том, что вместо изображение выводиться текст "pyimage 1". Как это исправить? (Если что, то писать не имя файла, а путь к нему, я пробовал, не помогло)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, Label
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage


tabl = Tk()
tabl.geometry("835x370")
tabl.title("Списки")
list = []
list1 = []


#Name
name = Label(text="Name: ")
name.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=45, ipady=6, padx=5, pady=5)
text1 = Entry(tabl)
text1.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=45, ipady=6, padx=5, pady=5)

#value
val = Label(text="Value: ")
val.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=45, ipady=6, padx=5, pady=5)
text2 = Entry(tabl)
text2.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=45, ipady=6, padx=5, pady=5)

#Добовление в таблицу
def spisok():
    text11 = text1.get()
    list.append(text11)
    text12 = text2.get()
    list1.append(text12)
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file="fish.png")
    tree.insert("", "end", values=(list, list1, img))


#Кнопка
butt = ttk.Button(text="+ Add: ", command=spisok)
butt.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=80, ipady=1, padx=60, pady=5)

#Таблица
column = ("Name", "Value", "Picture")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=column, show="headings")

tree.heading("Name", text="Name")
tree.heading("Value", text="Value")
tree.heading("Picture", text="Picture")
tree.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=80, ipady=1, padx=60, pady=5)


tabl.mainloop()
```

Выводиться так:[image: Вывод]

Comment: Вот этот ответ посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320072/4752653 . Там показано как добавлять через параметр image, только это добавляет картинку в дерево, а не в колонку. В общем-то не факт, что в колонку можно картинку добавить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307497/python-tkinter-treeview-add-an-image-as-a-column-value